# how can I invoke the last 3 commands in shell history

Tags: unix, shell, zsh

Lets say my last 3 commands were: 

`% rm foo.out
% myprog > foo.out
% cat foo.out`

I will like to invoke the last 3 with one stroke of the enter key, i.e. do some shell history commands which invke:
`% rm foo.out && myprog > foo.out && cat foo.out`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

History expansion works pretty similarly in bash and zsh, use !-N to reference the Nth previous command

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo bar
bar
$ echo baz
baz
$ !-3 && !-2 && !-1
echo foo && echo bar && echo baz
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: +1. If you want to execute all 3 commands regardless of their exit statuses, use `;` instead of `&&`